# Vaadin ActionHandler on Panel doesn't work

Tags: java, contextmenu, vaadin

I use Vaadin 6.8.8. I'm trying to add action handler to panel (to get context menu). The panel takes all the place of the window, but I caused the browser context menu when i do mouse right button click.

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {
    public MyPanel() {
    ...
            addActionHandler(new Action.Handler(){
                ...
            });
            setSizeFull();
     }
 }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those action related methods in Panel are for keyboard shorcuts. Only Tree, Table and TreeTable are the core components supporting context menu. To add a context menu to your panel, take a look at the [ContextMenu](http://vaadin.com/addon/contextmenu) add-on.